# What are the various positions in Prayer (Salat) called?

Tags: sharia, salat, practical-islam

I would like to know what the names of all the Pillars (Arkans) that are in a *Prayer(Salat)*. I know a few names *Ruku*, *Sajda*, etc. but I want to know the rest.

Please provide a detailed explanation.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform each action of Takbeer, Sujud, Tashahhud, Rukoo'?

Comment: I am asking the correct names of positions in order as they are performed while praying the salat. I guess they are called `Arkan`. Was searching for the word but couldn't find it.

Comment: Okay, there are 14 Arkan (pillars). I was just confirming.

Comment: @mtk: Thank you for your question. In order to receive to the point answers, please try to compose your question thoroughly before posting it.

Comment: Arkan and positions of body are not nessacirily the same. but it seems you mean Arkan of prayer.

Comment: @Abdullah: I am not an Arabic speaker. I thought *positions* and *Arkans* were the same. Please edit the question if necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 14 Arkan of Salat.  These 14 pillars must be done for the salat to be accepted.

1. Qiyam ma'il Qudrah fil fard (Standing, if able)
2. Takbeerat ul-ihram (Opening Takbir)
3. Qir`aat al-Fatihah (Recitation of Surat al-Fatihah)
4. Ruku` (Bowing)
5. Rafi' min ar-ruku' (Standing from bowing position)
6. Sujud 'alal a'dha a-sab'a (Prostrating on seven bones)
7. Al-i'tidhan min a sujud (Rising from sujud)
8. Al-jalsa bayna as-sajdatain (The sitting between the two sajdas)
9. Abta ma anina fi jami' arkani salat (Tranquility in all the pillars of the salat)
10. At-tartib baynal arkana salat (the proper order of the pillars of the salat)
11. At-tashahud al-akheer (The final tashahud)
12. A-julus li tashahud al-akheer (The sitting of the final tashahud)
13. A salatu 'ala nabiyan, salallaahu 'alaihi wa sallam (Sending salam upon the Prophet, salallaahu 'alaihi wa sallam)
14. Taslimatan (The two Taslims)

**Source:** [Conditions, Pillars, and Wajibat of the Salat, by Shaikh Taraheeb ad-Dosiri](http://www.salafitalk.net/st/viewmessages.cfm?Forum=10&Topic=8984)

These actions are based on the evidences from Qur'an and Sunnah. You can find them listed [here](http://www.subulassalaam.com/articles/article.cfm?article_id=98) for each action.

All Sunni madh-habs (Hanafi, Shafi'i, Maliki, Hanbali) at least contain all these 14 Arkan of Salat.

Comment: please mention the school. because prayer is different in different schools and all of them claim their prayer is based on the evidences from Qur'an and Sunnah

Answer (score 2):

According to [Fiqh](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/rulesofnamaaz2.html#951) of [Shia Islam](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/rulesofnamaaz2.html#951):

**Obligatory acts of prayer are eleven:**

1. Niyyat (intention)
2. Qiyam (standing erect)
3. Takbiratul Ehram (saying Allahu Akbar while commencing the prayers)
4. Ruku' (bowing)
5. Sajdatayn (two prostration)
6. Qira'at (recitation of Surah al-Hamd and other surah)
7. Zikr (prescribed recitation in Ruku' and Sajdah)
8. Tashahhud (bearing witness after completing the Sajdah of the second
   and the last Rak'at)
9. Salaam (Salutation)
10. Tartib (sequence)
11. Muwalat (to perform the different acts of prayers in regular
     succession).

**The elementals (Arkan) of Prayer are five:**

1. Intention (Niyyat)
2. Takbiratul Ehram
3. Standing before the Ruku'
4. Ruku'
5. Two Sajdah in every Rak'at.

> 951- *Some of the obligatory acts of prayers are elemental (Rukn). Hence, a person who does not offer them, whether intentionally or by
>   mistake, his prayers become void. Some other obligatory acts of
>   prayers are not elemental. Therefore, if they are omitted by mistake,
>   the prayers does not become void.([Reference](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/rulesofnamaaz2.html#951))

**Reference and further details:**

[Obligatory Acts Relating to Namaz](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/rulesofnamaaz2.html#951) from  [Risalah of Ayatullah al Uzama Syed Ali al-Husaini Seestani](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/)

[How to Perform the Daily Prayers](http://www.al-islam.org/nutshell/files/prayers.pdf) (illustrated positions of Salat)

[Prayer (Salat), According to Five Islamic Schools of Law](http://www.al-islam.org/encyclopedia/chapter7/6.html)

http://www.islamic-laws.com/salaat.htm

Comment: I didn't down-vote. But you answer seems to provide links only. Please revise your answer to cover OP's question properly. The intent of this website is to provide detailed answers not links to other sources. Thank you.

Comment: @Noah answer improved